# Proccess data from multiple forms in request.POST

Tags: python, django

Within my `CreateView` and `UpdateView` I am using a form for the main model and multiple forms to directly create/update related models:

```
class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
```

`MyModelForm` instantiates the required forms for the related fields I mentioned within itself.

My problem is that when I serialize the data and send it to the view, it doesn't know how to handle the data from the extra forms. When I access to `request.POST` this data gets discarded. I am serializing the forms like this:

```
let data = $('#main-form').serializeArray();
$('.other-form').each(function() {
    data.push({name: 'id-' + $(this).data('id'), value: $(this).serializeArray()});
});
```

This sends the following array to the server (I stringified it here for a clear display):

```
[
  {
    "name": "name",
    "value": "some name"
  },
  {
    "name": "id-194",
    "value": [
      {
        "name": "prop1",
        "value": "on"
      },
      {
        "name": "prop2",
        "value": "some prop"
      },
      {
        "name": "prop3",
        "value": "other prop"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "id-195",
    "value": [
      {
        "name": "prop2",
        "value": "some prop"
      },
      {
        "name": "prop3",
        "value": "other prop"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However the contents of `request.POST` are these:

```
<QueryDict: {u'name': [u'some name']}>
```

Notice how all other data is ignored. I can get to send it to the server the following way:

```
let data = $('#main-form').serializeArray();
$('.other-form').each(function() {
    data.push({name: 'id-' + $(this).data('id'), value: $(this).serialize()});
});
```

But this produces the following:

```
<QueryDict: {u'id-195': [u'prop1=on&prop2=some+prop&prop3=other+prop'], u'id-194': [u'displayable=on&prop2=some+prop&prop3=other+prop']}
```

Which is of course not what we want because all we get is a string, not prepared data. We need a dictionary I believe to initialize the forms appropriately.

This is my ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: editURL,
    data: data,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#mydiv').html(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your Ajax function? How are you sending that data?

Comment: @DanielRoseman there is not much mystery to it, but sure, I just added it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also confused about what data structure you want in Django. What is the form actually expecting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is hard to explain. I am populating those forms with data different to the form's instance, that's why I need to pass and handle request POST data to the forms' constructor.

Comment: Yes but without knowing what the constructor does with that data it's hard to help you. Perhaps you should show the form code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is passing a `initial` dictionary to the form constructors. The POST data is used as initial data.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `serializeArray` method generates a data structure suitable for converting to JSON. But you haven't done that, you're trying to send it as form-encoded data.

You should probably make it simpler by actually sending JSON, and parsing that at the other end.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: editURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (html) {
        $('#mydiv').html(html);
    }
});

...

class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        return {'data': json.loads(request.body)}
```

Note, I don't know what you are doing in your form to "instantiate the required forms for the related fields", but that's probably the wrong way to do it; you should be using a form and an inline related formset. Although, since this is Ajax posting to Django, it may be even better to switch to Django REST Framework and use serializers for this logic; those can deal easily with nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/). If the forms on your page are all the same form (IE you are just trying to make multiple records in the same model at once or whatever) you will probably find `formset_factory` quite useful.